# how to set "remote admin connections " option instead of sp_configure in azure db

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to set 'remote admin connections' on an azure database but the `sp_configure` command is not supported.

I used the `ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION` command but there is no "remote admin connections" option.

How can I do to solve this problem

Comment: Is this an Azure Managed Instance? Azure SQL Database? Azure Synapse? Azure Edge? Something else?

Comment: The DAC only operates on 127.0.0.1 tcp/1434... are you expecting to get that kind of access to an Azure SQL Database?

Comment: i am using Azure SQL Database!

Comment: actually i want to set on that option to login with only "id/ pw" not "id@servername / pw" . any other way to do it withour that option?

Comment: It is not necessary to enable the DAC connection with Azure SQL Database. DAC connections are possible without the option configured to 1. Have you tried with `SQLCMD`? I was able to connect with a DAC connection with or without `@servername`   appended to the id: `sqlcmd -S yourserver.database.windows.net -d yourdatabase -U youruser -P yourpassword -A`

Comment: i tried to connect with SSMS with private ip through private endpoint.  when i connect with ip, @servername is necessary. so i want to figure it  out how to connect withought it.

Comment: This query is also raised in MS Q&A forum. Find here the link for your tracking [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1063148/azure-sql-server-amp-sql-database-how-to-login-wit.html)